# Route returning 404 on apache server on all routes except /

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router to handle routes in an application and host it on apache server.

```
import Home from './home';
import steps from './steps';

const routing = (
  <BrowserRouter basename="/">
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/steps" component={steps} />
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

This code was working on godaddy server but after migrating to hostgator and on a new domain the route '/steps' is returning 404.

"Not Found
The requested URL /steps was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
This is the error being returned.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Usually, the Apache server returns a .js file with a React application in it to the browser, and the browser then runs on on the client side. Who do you want to return the 404 to whose requests?

Comment: The web server has to be configured to return your JS app for all routes, so that the react router can map the URL to a react component. 
Maybe this will help: https://gist.github.com/alexsasharegan/173878f9d67055bfef63449fa7136042